# OOP implementation issues for new progammer

Tags: c#, oop

I hope this is the right place to ask.

I am fairly new to .NET and I am having some problems regarding implementing OOP concepts.
I have followed a couple of books about c# and here is he problem.

By now, I know the OOP concepts theoretically, but I donot know 'How and When' to use these concepts in real world scenario. e.g. i know the DEFINITION of abstract, sealed, public classes and so on but i donot know WHEN to use them.

every books talks about person class or car class examples. but all those examples doesnt seem to work if i think of creating a for example simple inventory system. how would i define classes, methods, properties about an inventory system. this is where i alwys get stuck.

If possible please tell me of some book or resource to follow.

Thanks

Comment: I liked http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Principles-Patterns-Practices-C/dp/0131857258/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1330151386&sr=8-1. Don't be put off by the title. I also don't think this is the place to ask this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/392926/575376

Comment: I'd argue that books aren't going to be as helpful in this case. Why not? Because, as you pointed out yourself, your problem isn't a lack of theoretical understanding - if it were, I would read more books - your problem is a lack of concrete implementation and practice. As crude as it sounds, you're just going to have to practice. Books can only give you a direction to practice towards.

Comment: Imran, you are so right and I'm glad you see this so clearly now. Indeed, a lot of books show just Cat, Dog and Boy.

Comment: @jason: Indeed thats what my case is. But i asked for the resource in context of a continuing sample application development. As ogggre also observed the use of such examples is not very productive. Like they start talking about a cookie cutter to define concept of a class, i agree with it. but later on, when they are talking about some new concept, they give some other example of maybe a customer or student system. this breaks the understanding flow.

Comment: Thats why i asked for a resource which would start from building an application from scratch and by the time, the book is finished, all the concepts have been applied to that app and the app is working.

Comment: Let me know if you find that book ;]

Comment: Imran, take a closer look at Zen Buddhism. This is far from OOP, but at the same time it is closer than any OOP book you can find in the world.

Comment: To be truthful, I havent found any. I also searched for a tutorial series over the web, but to no avail. I think i'll have to learn it the hard way :). But this also opens up a need for such book. So many newbies like me will be honoured if someone produces such a book.

Comment: Regarding your question on how to approach OO design: try listing all the nouns and their relations. Use that to drive the design process. I give an example here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444818/how-to-create-perfect-oop-application/9445442#9445442

Comment: @Eric, This is such a good example you've given in the link. Now it somewhat makes sense to me about how to design the classes and relations. I'll work out these entities in my 'pharmacy project' and post it here for tuning. Thanks lots.

Comment: I would suggest the book 'Clean Code', it is a great book on how to code practically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to suggest a good book. Most of them describe OOP, but they don't describe "When" and "How deep". So I will give you two big advices:

1. Use minimal, the simplest abstractions and only when you feel they are required. Do not over-design, do not over-think. Keep things simple and loosely coupled
2. The second advice is an opposite compensation point for the first. Think in 3 years ahead. Just imagine how your system probably will look at that time. Predict the future requirements  and customer wishes. This will give you the hint about how deep your design should be detailed  and how much abstractions you should embed into system at the start to make your future bright

Comment: yes i think this is the way to start. i have (somewhat doubtfully) volunteered to create an inventory system for a pharmacy store. They have provided me with the data of their medicines. i need to make an app which will run on localhost and will used to keep track of purchases and sales as well as expiry issues and so on. And i want to work on it via OOP and .NET

Comment: I would add to that good advice: think early on about what things change and what things stay the same over time. For example: sales tax *policies* change all the time, but the fact that *there will be taxes computed on a sale* does not change. Isolate things that are likely to change and do not "bake in" dependencies on them.

Comment: @imran2155: Your *fundamental* problem is not an OO design problem. **Solve the database design problem first.**  Do not put the cart before the horse; your task is to *manage data*. OOP solves a certain kind of problem well but it is not a panacea; do not fall in love with OOP and use it even when it is neither appropriate nor necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574001/what-books-do-you-suggest-for-understanding-object-oriented-programming-design-d

[Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596008678)

[Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596007124)

Answer (score 0):

You might like to read Ron Jeffries' [*Extreme Programming Adventures in C#*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619492).  It's rather outdated in terms of C# versions, but it's a good read.  It is essentially his diary of learning C# by writing an XML editor.  It is also focused on XP methodologies, as indicated by the title, especially test-driven development.

By presenting the material in the form of a journal or diary, the author gives interesting insights into his thought processes; the flow of the narrative depicts his problem-solving process (pursuing a solution, then realizing it's no good, abandoning it for another solution, etc.).

That aspect is usually absent from programming books, which generally lay out ready-made solutions, sometimes without adequately explaining the problem being solved.  In real life, problems come before solutions, not the other way around.