# How to create the perfect OOP application

Tags: c#, oop

Recently I was trying for a company ‘x’. They sent me some set of questions and told me to solve only one.

The problem is like this -

Basic sales tax is applicable at a rate of 10% on all goods, except books, food, and medical products that are exempt.
Import duty is an additional sales tax applicable on all imported goods at a rate of 5%, with no exemptions.

When I purchase items I receive a receipt which lists the name of all the items and their price (including tax), finishing with the total cost of the items, and the total amounts of sales taxes paid.
The rounding rules for sales tax are that for a tax rate of n%, a shelf price of p contains (np/100 rounded up to the nearest 0.05) amount of sales tax.

“They told me, they are interested in the **Design Aspect** of your solution and would like to evaluate my **Object Oriented Programming Skills**.”

This is what they told in their own words

- For the solution, we would want you use either Java, Ruby or C#.
- We are interested in the DESIGN ASPECT of your solution and would like to evaluate your **Object Oriented Programming Skills**.
- You may use external libraries or tools for building or testing purposes. Specifically, you may use unit testing libraries or build tools available for your chosen language (e.g., JUnit, Ant, NUnit, NAnt, Test::Unit, Rake etc.)
- Optionally, you may also include a brief explanation of your design and assumptions along with your code.
- Kindly note that we are NOT expecting a web-based application or a comprehensive UI. Rather, we are expecting a simple, console based application and interested in your source code.

So I provided below code – you can just copy paste code and run in VS.

```
class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         try
         {
             double totalBill = 0, salesTax = 0;
             List<Product> productList = getProductList();
             foreach (Product prod in productList)
             {
                 double tax = prod.ComputeSalesTax();
                 salesTax += tax;
                 totalBill += tax + (prod.Quantity * prod.ProductPrice);
                 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Item = {0} : Quantity = {1} : Price = {2} : Tax = {3}", prod.ProductName, prod.Quantity, prod.ProductPrice + tax, tax));
             }
             Console.WriteLine("Total Tax : " + salesTax);
             Console.WriteLine("Total Bill : " + totalBill);                
        }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         }
         Console.ReadLine();
     }

    private static List<Product> getProductList()
     {
         List<Product> lstProducts = new List<Product>();
         //input 1
         lstProducts.Add(new Product("Book", 12.49, 1, ProductType.ExemptedProduct, false));
         lstProducts.Add(new Product("Music CD", 14.99, 1, ProductType.TaxPaidProduct, false));
         lstProducts.Add(new Product("Chocolate Bar", .85, 1, ProductType.ExemptedProduct, false));

        //input 2
         //lstProducts.Add(new Product("Imported Chocolate", 10, 1, ProductType.ExemptedProduct,true));
         //lstProducts.Add(new Product("Imported Perfume", 47.50, 1, ProductType.TaxPaidProduct,true));

        //input 3
         //lstProducts.Add(new Product("Imported Perfume", 27.99, 1, ProductType.TaxPaidProduct,true));
         //lstProducts.Add(new Product("Perfume", 18.99, 1, ProductType.TaxPaidProduct,false));
         //lstProducts.Add(new Product("Headache Pills", 9.75, 1, ProductType.ExemptedProduct,false));
         //lstProducts.Add(new Product("Imported Chocolate", 11.25, 1, ProductType.ExemptedProduct,true));
         return lstProducts;
     }
 }

public enum ProductType
 {
     ExemptedProduct=1,
     TaxPaidProduct=2,
     //ImportedProduct=3
 }

class Product
 {
     private ProductType _typeOfProduct = ProductType.TaxPaidProduct;
     private string _productName = string.Empty;
     private double _productPrice;
     private int _quantity;
     private bool _isImportedProduct = false;

    public string ProductName { get { return _productName; } }
     public double ProductPrice { get { return _productPrice; } }
     public int Quantity { get { return _quantity; } }

    public Product(string productName, double productPrice,int quantity, ProductType type, bool isImportedProduct)
     {
         _productName = productName;
         _productPrice = productPrice;
         _quantity = quantity;
         _typeOfProduct = type;
         _isImportedProduct = isImportedProduct;
     }

    public double ComputeSalesTax()
     {
         double tax = 0;
         if(_isImportedProduct) //charge 5% tax directly
             tax+=_productPrice*.05;
         switch (_typeOfProduct)
         {
             case ProductType.ExemptedProduct: break;
             case ProductType.TaxPaidProduct:
                 tax += _productPrice * .10;
                 break;
         }
         return Math.Round(tax, 2);
         //round result before returning
     }
 }
```

you can uncommnet input and run for different inputs.

I provided the solution but I was rejected.

"They said, they are unable to consider me for our current open positions because code solution is not satisfactory."

Please guide me what is missing here. Is this solution is not a good OOAD solution.
How can I improve my OOAD skills.
My seniors also says perfect OOAD application will also not work practically.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe they expected you to distinguish among the product types using an inheritance hierarchy, rather than an enumeration? (Although I think that approach would be rather convoluted for the given scenario.)

Comment: My guess is that they rejected your solution msotly because you didn't define any interfaces.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if someone asks you in an interview situation to demonstrate OOP skills, you should try to avoid using a switch statement - instead use an inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Should be posted in code review.

Comment: I had posted there also but couldn't get good solution there. But everyone can see my new solution i created after help from others

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/332077/how-to-develop-perfect-OOAD-application

here you can find my new code also.

Comment: I think I know for what you were preparing for. I did this in Java and got selected too. It's okay if you were not able to do this first time. But don't quite. Keep learning and trying. All the best.

Comment: Three words for you: Read this [book](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Applying_UML_and_patterns.html?id=r8i-4En_aa4C).  
  
It's got everything you need.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

First off **good heavens do not do financial calculations in double**. Do financial calculations in **decimal**; that is what it is for. Use double to solve *physics* problems, not *financial* problems.

The major design flaw in your program is that *policy is in the wrong place*.  Who is in charge of computing the taxes?  You've put *the product* in charge of computing the taxes, but when you buy an apple or a book or a washing machine, *the thing you are about to buy* is not responsible for telling you how much tax you're going to pay on it.  *Government policy* is responsible for telling you that. Your design massively violates the basic OO design principle that **objects should be responsible for their own concerns**, and not anyone else's.  The concern of a washing machine is washing your clothes, not charging the right import duty. If the tax laws change, you don't want to change *the washing machine object*, you want to change *the policy object*.

So, how to approach these sorts of problems in the future?

I would have started by highlighting every important noun in the problem description:

> **Basic sales tax** is applicable at a **rate** of 10% on all **goods**, except **books**, **food**, and **medical products** that are exempt. **Import duty** is an additional **sales tax** applicable on all **imported goods** at a **rate** of 5%, with no **exemptions**. When I purchase **items** I receive a **receipt** which lists the **name** of all the **items** and their **price** (including **tax**), finishing with the **total cost** of the items, and the total amounts of **sales taxes** paid. The rounding rules for **sales tax** are that for a tax rate of n%, a **shelf price** of p contains (np/100 rounded up to the nearest 0.05) amount of **sales tax**.

Now, what are the relationships between all those nouns?

- Basic Sales Tax is a kind of Sales Tax
- Import Duty is a kind of Sales Tax
- A Sales Tax has a Rate which is a Decimal
- Books are a kind of Item
- Food is a kind of Item
- Medical Products are a kind of Item
- Items may be Imported Goods
- An Item has a Name which is a String
- An Item has a Shelf Price which is a Decimal. (Note: does an item really have a price? two identical washing machines might be for sale for different prices at different stores, or at the same store at different times. A better design might be to say that a Pricing Policy relates an Item to its Price.)
- A Sales Tax Exemption Policy describes the conditions under which a Sales Tax is inapplicable on an Item.
- A Receipt has a list of Items, their prices and their taxes.
- A Receipt has a total
- A Receipt has a total tax

... and so on.  Once you have all the relationships between all the nouns worked out, then you can start designing a class hierarchy. There is an abstract base class Item. Book inherits from it. There is an abstract class SalesTax; BasicSalesTax inherits from it. And so on.

Comment: thanks for the reply. that was very helpful.

can you please guide me with some example also. thanks.

Comment: you need more than what was just provided?  Sounds like you need to learn more about how inheritance is implemented, and what polymorphism is.

Comment: Yes may be in practicle senarios. In with real life examples.

Comment: I'd be tempted to make Item a class and ItemType an enum property of that type.  I don't see any ItemType-specific functionality that would justify it being its own type.  Of course, going a bit overboard with your class hierarchy is a common way of making a toy program a bit meatier.

Comment: @sunder:  This answer is more than sufficient.  It is now your responsibility to develop your skills, perhaps using this as a first example.  Note that your example is the definition of a real-life example.  You failed a real-life interview because this real-life code needed a real-life design that you did not provide.

Comment: thanks for reply, i am gearing up for next real life interview. Based on this i created another design but could not post becaue of text limit. Thanks.

Comment: Use **double** to solve physics problems? please explain, what do you mean by physics problems?

Comment: @Narayan: `double` is ideal for situations where being within 0.00000001% of the right answer is more than enough. If you want to figure out how fast a brick is falling after half a second, do the math in doubles. When you do *financial* arithemtic in doubles you end up with answers like the price after tax is 43.79999999999999 dollars and that just looks silly even though it is extremely close to the correct answer.

Comment: @Narayan actually as per my knowledge i dont know why they said use decimal for financial problem not double.

But double has an issue. you store 1.0 in a double variable it will store it as 0.999999999 something.

Comment: +1 You've highlighted a remarkable exercise, which is to examine each noun in the stated problem, and then enumerate their relationships among one another. Great idea.

Comment: `doubles` don't give precise results, even more so after compound calculations; and accountants don't like losing pennies... This will print `False`: `Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Aggregate(0.00, (acc, i) => acc + 0.10) == 1.00)`, i.e., adding 0.10 10 times doesn't give you 1.00.

Comment: @Jordão: In decimal, adding 0.10 ten times does give 1.00. But adding 1.0/333.0 three hundred and thirty three times does not necessarily give one in either decimal or double. In decimal, fractions that have powers of ten in the denominator are exactly represented; in doubles, it is fractions with powers of two. Anything else is represented approximately.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Very true! It's just that I'd expect rounding to be applied to 1.0/333.0 before any financial calculations (if rounding up with 2 decimal places, it would be 0.01). Whereas 0.10 is already rounded :-)

Comment: @EricLippert Actually, the decimal number system can represent fractions whose denominators are not a power of ten; the real requirement is that the denominator have no prime factors other than the prime factors of ten.  Any fraction whose denominator is a power of two, a power of five, or the product of a power of two and a power of five has a finite decimal representation; two examples are 1/5 and 1/2.

Comment: @Eric Lippert Excellent suggestion about identifying the entities. I only have one problem with the suggestion. Creating a separate class for each Item category does not fit into the scope of the problem definition. A single Item class can contain a category attribute for creating any type of item. Creating one class per category makes sense when we are interested in additional properties for each category such as the manufacturer for a perfume or a pill.

Answer (score 38):

If company tells something about libraries like NUnit, JUnit or Test::Unit is more than probable that TDD is really importat to them. In your code sample is no tests at all.

I would try to demonstrate practical knowledge of:

- Unit tests (eg. NUnit, XUnit, ArchUnitNet, ...)
- Design patterns
- SOLID principles
- Clean Architecture
- Persistence (eg. Entity Framework, NHibernate)
- IoC Containers (eg. AutoFac)

I would like to recomend the [www.dimecasts.net](http://www.dimecasts.net) as impressive source of free, good quality screencasts which covers all above mentioned topics.

Answer (score 19):

This is highly subjective but here are a few points that I'd make about your code:

- In my opinion you mixed `Product` and `ShoppingCartItem`. `Product` should have the product name, tax status, etc. but not quantity. Quantity is not a property of a product - it'll be different for each customer of the company who buys that particular product.
- `ShoppingCartItem` should have a `Product` and the quantity. That way the customer can freely buy more or less of the same product. With your current setup that's not possible.
- Calculating the final tax also shouldn't be part of the `Product` - it should be part of something like `ShoppingCart` since the final tax calculation may involve knowing all products in the cart.

Comment: The only problem I have with this answer is it describes how to build a better product payment system (which is valid) but doesn't really elaborate on OOP methodologies. This could be implemented in any language. Without showing some sort of interfaces, inheritance, polymorphism, etc. he would still fail the test.

Comment: In reference to the last point: IMO best place for tax calculation is separate TaxCalculator class due to single resposibility principle.

Comment: thanks for reply but how practicle it is. does every company work in such extensive and pure OOPS models.

Comment: @shyamsunder There's nothing really pure about my answer. It doesn't use interfaces/inheritance which are important aspects of OOD, but it does show the most important principle - in my opinion - and that is putting responsibilities where they belong. As other answers pointed out, the main problem with your design is that you mixed up responsibilities among various actors and that will lead to problems when adding features. Most large software can only grow if they follow these principles.

Comment: Good answer but I also agree that tax calculation should be a separate object.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, this is a very good interview question. It's a good gauge of *many* skills.

There're many things you need to understand to provide a good answer (there is *no* perfect answer), both high-level and low-level. Here're a couple:

- **Domain Modeling** -> how do you create a good model of the solution? What objects do you create? How will they solve the requirements? Looking for the nouns is a good start, but how do you decide if your choice of entities is good? What *other* entities do you need? What *domain knowledge* do you need to solve it?
- **Separation of concerns, loose coupling, high cohesion** -> How do you separate out the parts of the design that have different concerns or rates of change and how do you relate them? How do you keep your design flexible and current?
- **Unit testing, refactoring, TDD** -> What's your *process* for coming up with a solution? Do you write tests, use mock objects, refactor, iterate?
- **Clean code, Language idioms** -> Do you use the features of your programming language to help you? Do you write understandable code? Do your levels of abstraction make sense? How maintainable is the code?
- **Tools**: Do you use source control? Build tools? IDEs?

From there, you can have many interesting discussions, involving design principles (like the SOLID principles), design patterns, analysis patterns, domain modeling, technology choices, future evolution paths (e.g. what if I add a database, or a rich UI layer, what needs to change?), trade-offs, non-functional requirements (performance, maintainability, security, ...), acceptance testing, etc...

I won't comment on how you should change your solution, just that you should focus more on these concepts.

But, I can show you how [I (partially) solved this problem](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2012/03/some-oo-design.html), just as an example (in Java). Look in the [`Program` class](https://github.com/codecrafter/orders/blob/master/src/main/java/codecrafter/orders/Program.java) to see how it all comes together to print this receipt:

```
------------------ THIS IS YOUR ORDER ------------------
(001)                Domain Driven Design -----   $69.99
(001)    Growing Object Oriented Software -----   $49.99
(001)                 House M.D. Season 1 -----   $29.99
(001)                 House M.D. Season 7 -----   $34.50
(IMD)    Growing Object Oriented Software -----    $2.50
(BST)                 House M.D. Season 1 -----    $3.00
(BST)                 House M.D. Season 7 -----    $3.45
(IMD)                 House M.D. Season 7 -----    $1.73
                                SUB-TOTAL -----  $184.47
                                TAX TOTAL -----   $10.68
                                    TOTAL -----  $195.15
---------------- THANKS FOR CHOOSING US ----------------
```

You should definitely take a look at those books :-)

Just as a caveat: my solution is still very incomplete, I just focused on the happy path scenario in order to have a good foundation to build on.

Comment: I went through your solution and found it pretty interesting. Although I feel that the Order class should not be responsible for printing a Reciept. Similarly, the TaxMethod class should not be responsible for calculating tax. Also, TaxMethodPractice should not contain a list of TaxMethod. Instead, a class called SalesPolicy should contain this list. A class called SalesEngine should be passed a SalesPolicy, an Order and a TaxCalculator. SalesEngine will apply the SalesPolicy on the items in the Order and calculate the Tax using the TaxCalculator

Comment: @bot: interesting observations.... Right now, `Order` prints the receipt, but `Receipt` knows about its own formatting. Also, TaxMethodPractice is kind of a tax policy, it holds all the taxes that apply to a certain scenario. TaxMethods _are_ tax calculators. I feel that you're only missing some higher level _binding_ class, like your proposed SalesEngine. It's an interesting idea.

Comment: I just feel that every class must have a single well defined responsibility and classes that represent real world objects should behave in a fashion that's in line with the real world. For that matter a TaxMethod can be split into two classes. A TaxCriteria and a TaxCalculator. Similarly an Order must not print a receipt. A ReceiptGenerator should be passed a Receipt for generating a receipt.

Comment: @bot: I completely agree! Good designs are [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod)! A TaxMethod _is_ a tax calculator, and a TaxEligibilityCheck _is_ a tax criteria. They're separate entities. As for the receipt, yes, splitting the generating part would further improve the design.

Comment: You are using TaxMethod to create a representation of a basic sales tax and an import duty tax. In that regards, TaxMethod can be said to be a representation of a policy. A policy must not calculate tax just like a calculator must not decide whether a policy is applicable or not

Comment: @bot: to me, a policy is a set of rules that apply to a certain scenario. A _policy_ is represented by a `TaxingPractice`, because it encapsulates all taxes that are _in effect_ at a point in time. A `TaxMethod` is a simple class that _calculates_ a specific tax. A `TaxEligibilityCheck` is used by a tax method to check whether taxes are applicable. Now, for sure this could all have been done differently, and it would be equally valid. And of course I invite you to evolve the design, or even create your own that incorporates some of my ideas.

Comment: That idea comes from the [specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern), take a look!

Comment: In your case, you would create an AndEligibilityCheck and pass an array of TaxEligibilityCheck to the and method? The isEligibility method can iterate through the array of TaxEligibilityCheck and return true only if the item satisfies all the isEligible methods of passed in TaxEligobilityCheck instances? Would this be a right way to achieve the goal if I wanted to use your idea?

Comment: @bot: yes, that would be the way to do it; possibly alongside a `OrEligibilityCheck` and a `NotEligibilitycheck`.

Answer (score 12):

Except the fact that you are using a class called product, you have not demonstrated you know what inheritance is, you have not created multiple classed inheriting from Product, no polymorphism. The problem could have been solved using multiple OOP concepts (even just to show that you know them). This is an interview problem so you want to show how much you know.

I wouldn't however turn into depression right now. The fact that you didn't demonstrate them here does not mean you don't already know them or are not able to learn them.

You just need a little more experience with either OOP or interviews.

Good luck!

Comment: actually this was my first design, i created another one but can't show you as character limit is exceeding.

Comment: can you demonstrate it with the help of any example.

Comment: @sunder: You can just update the question with your new design.

Answer (score 10):

People who have start learning programming with OOP don't have great problems to understand what it means, because it is **just as in real life**. If you have skills with other programming familly than OO, it could be more difficult to understand.

First of all, turn-off your screen, or exit your favorite IDE. Take a **paper** and a **pencil** and make a list of *entities*, *relations*, *people*, *machines*, *processes*, *stuff*, etc. ***everything*** that could be encountered into your final program.

Second, try to get the different **basic** entities. You will understand that some can share  *properties* or *abilities*, you have to put it in **abstract objects**. You should start to draw a nice schema of your program.

Next you have to put fonctionnalities (methods, functions, subroutines, call it as you want): for example, a *product* object should not be able to *compute sales tax*. A *sales engine* object should.

Don't feel trouble with all the big words(*interfaces*, *properties*, *polymorphism*, *heritage*, etc. ) and design patterns in a first time, don't even try to make beautiful code or whatever... Just think to simple **objects** and **interractions between** it **as in  real life**.

After, try to read some serious concise litterature about this. I think [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Object_Oriented_Programming) are a really good way to begin and then just read stuff about [GoF and Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) and [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language).

Comment: +1 for "First of all, turn-off your screen". I think the power of thinking too often mistaken for the power of computing.

Comment: +1 for taking the simplest approach of using pencil and paper. Many times people get confused when sitting in front of the IDE :)

Comment: Some scientists said that our brain is inattentive when watching a screen. When I study software architecture design, our teacher makes us working on paper. He don't mind of powerful UML softwares. What is important is to understand the things first.

Answer (score 4):

First don't mix `Product` class with Receipt(`ShoppingCart`) class, the `quantity` should be part of `ReceipItem`(`ShoppingCartItem`), as well as `Tax`&`Cost`. The `TotalTax`&`TotalCost` should be part of `ShoppingCart`.

My `Product` class, has only `Name`&`Price` & some readonly properties like `IsImported`:

```
class Product
{
    static readonly IDictionary<ProductType, string[]> productType_Identifiers = 
        new Dictionary<ProductType, string[]>
        {
            {ProductType.Food, new[]{ "chocolate", "chocolates" }},
            {ProductType.Medical, new[]{ "pills" }},
            {ProductType.Book, new[]{ "book" }}
        };

    public decimal ShelfPrice { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsImported { get { return Name.Contains("imported "); } }

    public bool IsOf(ProductType productType)
    {
        return productType_Identifiers.ContainsKey(productType) &&
            productType_Identifiers[productType].Any(x => Name.Contains(x));
    }
}

class ShoppringCart
{
    public IList<ShoppringCartItem> CartItems { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalTax { get { return CartItems.Sum(x => x.Tax); } }

    public decimal TotalCost { get { return CartItems.Sum(x => x.Cost); } }
}

class ShoppringCartItem
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal Tax { get; set; }

    public decimal Cost { get { return Quantity * (Tax + Product.ShelfPrice); } }
}
```

Your tax calculation part is coupled with `Product`. A Product doesn't define tax policies it's Tax classes. Based on the problem's description, there are two kind of Sales Taxes: `Basic` and `Duty` taxes. You can use [`Template Method Design Pattern`](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3199484/c-sharp/how-to-implement-the-template-method-design-pattern-in-c.html) to achieve it:

```
abstract class SalesTax
{
    abstract public bool IsApplicable(Product item);
    abstract public decimal Rate { get; }

    public decimal Calculate(Product item)
    {
        if (IsApplicable(item))
        {
            //sales tax are that for a tax rate of n%, a shelf price of p contains (np/100)
            var tax = (item.ShelfPrice * Rate) / 100;

            //The rounding rules: rounded up to the nearest 0.05
            tax = Math.Ceiling(tax / 0.05m) * 0.05m;

            return tax;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

class BasicSalesTax : SalesTax
{
    private ProductType[] _taxExcemptions = new[] 
    { 
        ProductType.Food, ProductType.Medical, ProductType.Book 
    };

    public override bool IsApplicable(Product item)
    {
        return !(_taxExcemptions.Any(x => item.IsOf(x)));
    }

    public override decimal Rate { get { return 10.00M; } }
}

class ImportedDutySalesTax : SalesTax
{
    public override bool IsApplicable(Product item)
    {
        return item.IsImported;
    }

    public override decimal Rate { get { return 5.00M; } }
}
```

And finally a class to apply taxes:

```
class TaxCalculator
{
    private SalesTax[] _Taxes = new SalesTax[] { new BasicSalesTax(), new ImportedDutySalesTax() };

    public void Calculate(ShoppringCart shoppringCart)
    {
        foreach (var cartItem in shoppringCart.CartItems)
        {
            cartItem.Tax = _Taxes.Sum(x => x.Calculate(cartItem.Product));
        }

    }
}
```

You can try them out at [MyFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zz6Jp4).

Answer (score 2):

A very good starting point about design rules are the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles.

For instance the Open Closed principle states that if you want to add new functionality you don't have to add code to existing class, but rather add new class.

For your sample application this would mean that adding new sales tax would require adding new class. The same goes for different products that are exceptions to the rule.

The rounding rule obviously goes in separate class - the Single Responsibility principle states that every class has a single responsibility.

I think trying to write the code yourself would bring by far more benefit than simply writing a good solution and pasting it here.

A simple algorithm to write the perfect designed program would be:

1. Write some code that solves the problem
2. Check whether the code complies to the SOLID principles
3. If there are rule violations than goto 1.

Answer (score 2):

A perfect OOP implementation is completely debatable. From what I see in your question, you could modularize the code based on the role they perform to compute the final price like Product, Tax, ProductDB and so on.

1. `Product` could be an abstract class and the derived types like Books, Food could be inherited from it. Tax applicability can be decided by the derived types. Product would tell whether the tax is applicable or not based on the derived class.
2. `TaxCriteria` can be an enum and the this can be specified during purchase (imported, Sales Tax applicability).
3. `Tax` class will compute tax based on `TaxCriteria`.
4. Having a `ShoppingCartItem` as suggested by [XXBBCC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9444935/1037019) can encapsulate Product and Tax instances and it is a great way to segregate product details with quantity, total price with tax etc.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

From a strictly OOA/D perspective, one major issue I see is that most of your class attributes have the redundant name of the class in the attribute name.  e.g. **product** Price, typeOf **Product**.  In this case, everywhere you use this class you will have overly verbose and somewhat confusing code, e.g. product.productName.  Remove the redundant class name prefix/suffixes from your attributes.

Also, I did not see any classes concerned with purchasing and creating a receipt as was asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great example of an OO pattern for Products, Tax, etc...  Notice the use of Interfaces, which is essential in OO design.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/185426-design-patterns-strategy/

Comment: I'd prefer making product an (abstract) class over making it an interface. I wouldn't make each product a separate class either. At most I'd create one class per category.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - Most of the time you need both but if you're trying to land a job as an architect, I'd choose to implement Interfaces over an Abstract class.

Comment: Interfaces in this example have no sense at all. They only lead to code duplication in each class implementing them. Each class implements it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Attacked the Cost with Tax problem using a Visitor pattern.

```
public class Tests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        public void Input1Test()
        {
            var items = new List<IItem> {
                new Book("Book", 12.49M, 1, false),
                new Other("Music CD", 14.99M, 1, false),
                new Food("Chocolate Bar", 0.85M, 1, false)};

            var visitor = new ItemCostWithTaxVisitor();

            Assert.AreEqual(12.49, items[0].Accept(visitor));
            Assert.AreEqual(16.49, items[1].Accept(visitor));
            Assert.AreEqual(0.85, items[2].Accept(visitor));
        }

        [Test]
        public void Input2Test()
        {
            var items = new List<IItem> {
                new Food("Bottle of Chocolates", 10.00M, 1, true),
                new Other("Bottle of Perfume", 47.50M, 1, true)};

            var visitor = new ItemCostWithTaxVisitor();

            Assert.AreEqual(10.50, items[0].Accept(visitor));
            Assert.AreEqual(54.65, items[1].Accept(visitor));
        }

        [Test]
        public void Input3Test()
        {
            var items = new List<IItem> {
                new Other("Bottle of Perfume", 27.99M, 1, true),
                new Other("Bottle of Perfume", 18.99M, 1, false),
                new Medicine("Packet of headache pills", 9.75M, 1, false),
                new Food("Box of Chocolate", 11.25M, 1, true)};

            var visitor = new ItemCostWithTaxVisitor();

            Assert.AreEqual(32.19, items[0].Accept(visitor));
            Assert.AreEqual(20.89, items[1].Accept(visitor));
            Assert.AreEqual(9.75, items[2].Accept(visitor));
            Assert.AreEqual(11.80, items[3].Accept(visitor));
        }
    }

    public abstract class IItem : IItemVisitable
    { 
        public IItem(string name,
            decimal price,
            int quantity,
            bool isImported)
            {
                Name = name;
                Price = price;
                Quantity = quantity;
                IsImported = isImported;
            }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public bool IsImported { get; set; }

        public abstract decimal Accept(IItemVisitor visitor);
    }

    public class Other : IItem, IItemVisitable
    {
        public Other(string name, decimal price, int quantity, bool isImported) : base(name, price, quantity, isImported)
        {
        }

        public override decimal Accept(IItemVisitor visitor) => Math.Round(visitor.Visit(this), 2);
    }

    public class Book : IItem, IItemVisitable
    {
        public Book(string name, decimal price, int quantity, bool isImported) : base(name, price, quantity, isImported)
        {
        }

        public override decimal Accept(IItemVisitor visitor) => Math.Round(visitor.Visit(this),2);
    }

    public class Food : IItem, IItemVisitable
    {
        public Food(string name, decimal price, int quantity, bool isImported) : base(name, price, quantity, isImported)
        {
        }

        public override decimal Accept(IItemVisitor visitor) => Math.Round(visitor.Visit(this), 2);
    }

    public class Medicine : IItem, IItemVisitable
    {
        public Medicine(string name, decimal price, int quantity, bool isImported) : base(name, price, quantity, isImported)
        {
        }

        public override decimal Accept(IItemVisitor visitor) => Math.Round(visitor.Visit(this), 2);
    }

    public interface IItemVisitable
    {
        decimal Accept(IItemVisitor visitor);
    }

    public class ItemCostWithTaxVisitor : IItemVisitor
    {
        public decimal Visit(Food item) => CalculateCostWithTax(item);

        public decimal Visit(Book item) => CalculateCostWithTax(item);

        public decimal Visit(Medicine item) => CalculateCostWithTax(item);

        public decimal CalculateCostWithTax(IItem item) => item.IsImported ?
            Math.Round(item.Price * item.Quantity * .05M * 20.0M, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 20.0M + (item.Price * item.Quantity)
            : item.Price * item.Quantity;

        public decimal Visit(Other item) => item.IsImported ?
            Math.Round(item.Price * item.Quantity * .15M * 20.0M, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 20.0M + (item.Price * item.Quantity)
            : Math.Round(item.Price * item.Quantity * .10M * 20.0M, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 20.0M + (item.Price * item.Quantity);
    }

    public interface IItemVisitor
    {
        decimal Visit(Food item);
        decimal Visit(Book item);
        decimal Visit(Medicine item);
        decimal Visit(Other item);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please ensure you explain your answer in response to the question. The OP is not just seeking a solution but why a solution is better/worse.