# Object-Oriented Design

Tags: oop, object

I was given an assignment which is write a simple program to print out the receipt for customers at a grocery store. Know that **basic sales tax** is applicable at a rate of 10% on all goods, except books, food, and medical products that are exempt. **Import duty** is an additional sales tax applicable on all imported goods at a rate of 5%, with no exemptions.

Sample input: 1 book at $10, 1 imported chocolate bar at $5 and so on.

I want to make the program as object oriented as possible. So my hierarchy is like this:

The top hierarchy is abstract class Item(name,price), then I will have class SaleTaxItem (items that need to pay 10% tax) and NonSaleTax item class extends from Item. The question is should I just create a Boolean variable called isImported inside each class above so that I will know when to charge 5% more? Or should I create a new class for imported item?

The design is very important for this assignment so I want to make it perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just write a method `getTax()` which return 10% for SaleTaxItem and 10%+5% for items eligable for import duty (overriding perhaps?)? I don't think boolean is a good scalable choice: imagine one day we've introduced a new tax: do we need to introduce new boolean? do we need to encode it in int?

Comment: Ya I have getTax() in which I currently use a boolean to decide whether or not to charge 5% import tax. And I implement is_import boolean in Item class. If I do not use a boolean so what should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create the perfect OOP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444818/how-to-create-the-perfect-oop-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are huge discussions on when to used inheritance and when not to. In this case, I would *not* use inheritance to model your items.

Why? Because in real life these tax and duty rules change frequently both in time, space (eg which state you're in) and also by the type of company you're running. If you have to change the class hierarchy each time local and federal governments change their regulations, you're doomed - the update will change the classes of which you already have instances - your items.

Another consideration: if you use classes to (effectively) 'tag' a sale as having tax and/or duty, you will end up with some items having no tagging interfaces, and some with multiple - i.e. using multiple inheritance. You need four classes. Add in some additional rules, and you have a class explosion (factorial the number of taxes/duties to consider).

An alternate implementation is to have a property that is the collection of taxes and duties the item has. So you have two classes,:

- Item

  - List: taxes
- Tax

  - String: name
  - Double: percent

Tax has a number of global instances - SalesTax and ImportDuty. Then an item has zero, one or two Tax instances in the list (and the list also implies *order* that the taxes are applied).

This last approach is also much better future-proofed for tax changes, including the addition of new taxes

**EDIT** Overnight I have an improved suggestion:

[image]

There are two 'wings' to the diagram:

1. AbstractItem hierarchy, handling the Item and its taxes
2. TaxOrDuty hierarchy and an algorithm in TaxAssessor.

The AbstractItem uses the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) on an Item, wrapping the Item in layers of taxes - each layer modelled by TaxedItem. The outmost layer is an Item wrapped in all applicable taxes, and, using the decorator pattern, looks and behaves as an Item would, except for an inflated price. The AbstractItem has several useful methods:

- getPrice(): Returns the full price of the item
- getAllTaxes(): Pass in an empty list, and the method recurses over the decorators collecting the TaxOrDuty instances. This is important to be able to itemize the taxes on a decorated Item
- getUntaxedItem(): Recurses through the decorations until it finds the Item, which it returns. This allows easy retrieval of the raw Item from a decorated Item.

On the taxes side, there is a class TaxOrDuty that models the abstract behaviour of taxes in general. In this naive implementation, every tax has a flat rate, but you could easily push that behaviour down into a FlatRateTax class. Its methods are:

- getRate(): Abstract method that returns the tax or duties *rate*. This is implemented on the subclasses
- computeTax() method takes an Item and computes the taxes for it based on getRate()
- isApplicable() is an abstract method that returns true if the tax is applicable for the Item. This is implemented on SalesTax (always returns true) and ImportDuty (returns Item.isImported)

The TaxAssessor is a class responsible for co-ordinating the assignment of applicable taxes. It contains a list of all TaxOrDuty instances (in this case just one instance of SalesTax and one of ImportDuty). Its method applyTaxes(Item) iterates over this collection calling isApplicable(). For any TaxOrDuty that returns true, the TaxAssessor wraps the Item in a new instance of TaxedItem (which of course references the TaxOrDuty):

```
AbstractItem applyTaxes(Item item) {
    taxed = item;
    for (TaxOrDuty td : taxes) {
          if (td.isApplicable(item)) {
              taxed = new TaxedItem(td, taxed);
    return taxed;
```

So your overall answer will be something like:

```
Item item = new Item("Book", 10.0, false); // New $10 book, not imported
AbstractItem withTaxes = taxAssessor.applyTaxes(item);
double taxedPrice = withTaxes.getPrice();
List<TaxOrDuty> applicableTaxes = withTaxes.getAllTaxes(new List<TaxOrDuty>());
```

The major advantages of this model are:

- New taxes are pluggable
- The tax assessment and computation algorithms are part of the Tax rather than in Item, so very complex taxes can be modelled independently and correctly in their own class
- Responsibilities are obvious (to me) and clearly demarcated

Comment: Is there anyway I can identify which item is taxable? I mean for example, I have only 1 class Item, when I create a new Item and feed a name "chocolate" to the constructor, the constructor will recognize that chocolate is food and apply tax to the price?!

Comment: @CharlieVictor: I have updated my answer with a much improved model which answers this question.